# Package transitive deps in Bazel

Tags: c++, bazel, bazel-rules

I would like to package lets say a binary with the `pkg_tar` command. But I would also automatically like it to include all deps to that binary, for example all .so files from other Bezel targets that are referenced with deps. Is it possible?

```
pkg_tar(
    name = "example",
    srcs = ["//myprogram"], # This only packages myprogram target
    mode = "0644",
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently, this feature isn't officially supported. You have three basic options:

- explicitly enumrate all deps
- use one of "hacks" from https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1920
- use undocumented `include_runfiles = True` feature https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg/issues/145

Answer (score 1):

Setting the (undocumented) `include_runfiles = True` will include the shared object and any other [runfiles](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/rules.html#runfiles) of all the transitive dependencies.